# Is it possible to return a worksheet type variable in a function?

Tags: excel, vba

In this project I'm developing, I created many Subs that all use the same three workbooks. But is there a better way to use these workbooks' sheets  without having to write them down everytime I create a new Sub? I tried returning it in a function but it does not work.

```
Function defineWorksheet() As Worksheet

Dim wk_Base_18 As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws_18 As Excel.Worksheet

Set wk_Base_18 = Excel.Workbooks("2019.01.03.xlsb")
Set ws_18 = wk_Base_18.Worksheets("Planilha1")

ws_18

End Function
```

> error 91

Comment: It looks like you're trying to define public variables?  If that's the case, use `Sub` instead of `Function` since your function isn't actually returning anything.  If it is supposed to, then you should add `Set defineWorksheet = ws_18` just before the end of your function.

Comment: Thanks, just realised your idea could work too but nonetheless thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can declare them as a global variable.

```
Public ws1 As Worksheet
```

Then instantiate the global variable during the application load event of the [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) application

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
     Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheetName")
End Sub
```

And now, you can refer to it via the variable, eg.

```
Dim x as Integer: x = ws1.Range("B5")
```

Comment: Thanks for saving me!

Comment: @Daniel if the sheet exists at compile-time in `ThisWorkbook`, there already is a global object/Worksheet variable for it, named after whatever that sheet module's `(Name)` property is - declaring a variable for, let alone pulling that object from the `ThisWorkbook.Sheets` or `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` collection, is perfectly redundant - only do this for sheets created at run-time, or sheets that are in workbooks loaded at run-time.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I actually changed this line because I'm saving the values to another workbook not `this.workbook` but thanks for the info though

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is sound, you just need to create one function per object:

```
Function wk_Base_18() as workbook
    Set wk_Base_18 = Excel.Workbooks("2019.01.03.xlsb")
End Function

Function ws_18() as worksheet
    Set ws_18 = wk_Base_18.Worksheets("Planilha1")
End Function
```

Then whenever you go to use the variable ws_18 or wk_Base_18, you will be calling these same functions.

Comment: Interesting idea I must say but the thing is that i'll be mostly using these variables to count rows and columns, for example: rowsCount = ws_18.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row so I think the compiler might not recognize it there in the middle of a line...

Comment: The compiler will definitely be fine with it. I've used this approach before.